# MVC 4: Is it possible to post only modified rows back to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My project has a main form that displays many rows. In the example below the divs with id = "Grid"* will be replaced by partial views containing tables. The form is an Ajax form and is strongly typed.  Is there a way to send only rows that have been modified back to the controller and have the model contain only those rows?

```
@model Models.myModel;

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save", "myController", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "AllGrids" }, new { id = "frm" }))
    { 
    <div id="AllGrids">
        <table id="EvidenceGrids" style="width: 1200px">
            <tr>
                <td style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin">
                    <div id="Grid1"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin">
                    <div id="Grid2"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin">
                    <div id="Grid3"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
    }

    public ActionResult Save (Model m)
    {
        use model as needed
    }
```